# Valgrind changes working directory with CTest in KDevelop

Tags: c++, cmake, valgrind, ctest

I am starting a test with Helgrind using Ctest:

```
find_program(VALGRIND_EXECUTABLE valgrind)
message(STATUS "Valgrind in ${VALGRIND_EXECUTABLE}")
configure_file(project.supp project.supp)
set(BOOST_TEST_ARGS --catch_system_errors=no)

set(VALGRIND_HELGRIND_OPTIONS --tool=helgrind --suppressions=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/project.supp --xml=yes --read-var-info=yes)
add_test(NAME TestHelgrind COMMAND ${VALGRIND_EXECUTABLE} ${VALGRIND_HELGRIND_OPTIONS} --xml-file=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test.xml ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test ${BOOST_TEST_ARGS})
```

However the working directory in the test seems to be /usr/bin.
Even when specifying:

```
WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
```

which should be the default I guess.
It works if I use memcheck for example.

The test is started from KDevelop.

Comment: How have you found out that working directory **seems** to be /usr/bin?

Comment: In the C++ program I used std::cout << "Current working dir: " << boost::filesystem::current_path() << std::endl;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with KDevelop. Running the test from the console did not change the working directory.

I've created a bug report: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=349378